# Excel Forumla - Average days from group of Dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of Dates that I would like to get the average number of days between ALL dates, collectively.

What I mean by that is lets say I have Table1:

```
        A          B
  ------------------------
1 | Date      | Desc     |
  ------------------------
2 | 6/16/2016 |          |
  ------------------------
3 | 7/01/2016 |          |
  ------------------------
4 | 7/19/2016 |          |
  ------------------------
5 | 8/08/2016 |          |
  ------------------------
6 | Etc       |          |
  ------------------------
```

I don't want the average days between MAX() & MIN(). I want it for each new entry, but collectively, if that makes sense. I know I can get an individual rows total # of days by using `=DAYS(A3,A2)` an so on for each row, then use AVERAGE() for all those individual row totals. But how can I do this with a formula autonomously?

**EDIT**

Based on your answer nightcrawler23, here is what I came up with my table because it is dynamic:

```
{=AVERAGE(INDEX(Table1,2,1):INDEX(Table1,ROWS(Table1),1)-INDEX(Table1,1,1):INDEX(Table1,ROWS(Table1)-1,1))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use the below formula entered as an array i.e. Type the formula and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=AVERAGE(A3:A5-A2:A4)
```

**Update1**

For varying number of rows, you can try

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A3:A"&COUNT(A:A)+1)-INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNT(A:A)))
```

The formula has addresses input as strings, so if your data location changes, the formula needs to be revised.

**Update2**

Since you are using named ranges, try ti use this formulae. Table1 is Column A:A

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDEX(Table1,2),1,0,COUNT(Table1)-1,1)-OFFSET(INDEX(Table1,2),0,0,COUNT(Table1)-1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you nightcrawler, that was fast, why is it always so easy for other people :) - I did forget to mention to you that my data is dynamic. I have edited my question with your formula, can you please review it for correctness. Basically, I don't know where the last row will be as it will always be changing, or if the table gets moved etc.

Comment: Revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula if it is a dynamic range. It will give you the no. of days.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A:A),"",IF(LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),A:A)<>"",DATEDIF(A2,LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),A:A),"YD")))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, but I need the average days between each date, as one answer, not the # of days you provided. Thank you for trying though